# frequency of a word that is close to itself in a list

Tags: python, awk

I have 2 files where the word "test" is found 3 times each.

```
distributed.txt

this
is
only
a
test
to
see
if
test
is
same
as
test
```

Another file has the word "test". But it is repeated immediately or after 1 or 2 words.

```
closer.txt

this
is
only
a
test
to
test
test
see
if
is
same
as
```

The word "test" appear 3 times in both the files. Hence the perecentage is same.
But it is closer to each other in one file and more distributed in another. Is there any method in Machine learning to know how close or far a word is repeated in the given list?

```
$ wc -l closer.txt
13 closer.txt

$ grep test closer.txt | wc -l
3

$ wc -l distributed.txt
13 distributed.txt

$ grep test distributed.txt | wc -l
3
```

Comment: You mean something like "evenly distributed"?

Comment: Yes. That is correct term.

Comment: I guess machine learning or NLP must have a method/ module for this. Can I add that tag @Wiktor Stribiżew ?

Comment: @shantanuo This is not a question about machine learning. Neither are libraries, these are just general notions. Besides, if you just ask for a library, it is an offtopic question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it following way: 1) get number of lines (indices) of target words 2) compute standard deviation, in order to do so create script in directory where you have your txt files, name it for example `wordspread.py`:

```
import fileinput
import statistics
word = "test"
indices = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    if line.strip()==word:
        indices.append(fileinput.lineno())
print(statistics.stdev(indices))
```

then in console do

```
python wordspread.py distributed.txt
python wordspread.py closer.txt
```

these commands will output respectively

```
4.0
1.5275252316519465
```

higher value mean bigger spread. `fileinput` and `statistics` are built-in modules so you do not have to install anything beyond `python`. Beware that this solution assumes that number of occurences of given word is roughly similar in your files and never smaller than 2.

Comment: The production file has more than 50 million words. word 'test' appear around 4000 times. Your wordspread script returns 14133024.901812198 Does it mean it is evenly distributed?

Comment: @shantanuo my solution is for comparing 2 or more files

Comment: It works very well for a single file as well. If the number is that big then the spread is more distributed. I just checked. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can get all the index location of an element 'test' from each file -

```
For 1st file. = [4, 8, 12]
for 2nd file. = [4, 6, 7]
```

From the index, we can get the difference between the index to check how far the elements are from each other. This can be done via np.diff(list)

```
For 1st file. = [4, 4]
For 2nd file. = [2, 1]
```

After that, we can take the mean to get the average distance.

```
for 1st file, it's = 4
for the 2nd file, it's = 1.5
```

This means the element 'test' is more closely located in the 2nd file.

```
import numpy as np
from statistics import mean

file_list = ['distributed.txt', 'closer.txt']
for file in file_list:
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = [ line.strip() for line in f ]
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(lines) if x == "test"] # this will return the list of index values
    diff = np.diff(indices) # to obtain the difference list
    print(mean(map(int,v)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way.

1. First calculate where each line matches your target and note the line number;
2. Then, calculate the distance between each point seen. Add the start and end of file line numbers if there is no target on that line;
3. Finally, take the stddev of the distance between targets.

Here is a Python function that wraps all that up:

```
import statistics   
import re 

def dist_space(fn):
    ln=[]
    with open (fn) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if re.search(r'^test$', line):
                ln.append(i)
    
    if ln[0]!=0: ln = [0]+ln 
    if ln[-1]!=i: ln.append(i)
    
    return statistics.stdev((j-i) for i,j in zip(ln,ln[1:]))
```

Testing against your examples:

```
>>> dist_space('distributed.txt')
0.0
# ie, perfectly spaced between marks


>>> dist_space('closer.txt') 
1.8257418583505538
# a standard deviation of 1.8 amongst the space distance -- not even
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution (`lst` is your list of words):

```
import numpy as np

idxs = np.argwhere(np.array(lst) == 'test').flatten()
uniform_idxs = np.linspace(-1, len(lst), idxs.size + 2)[1:-1]

uniformity_index = np.abs(uniform_idxs - idxs).mean()
```

This solution is easily interpretable. Let's say you have 11 words and word 'test' is used 3 times. Then you have perfect uniformity (`uniformity_index = 0`) in this case:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'test', 'c', 'd', 'test', 'e', 'f', 'test', 'g', 'h']
```

Instead, if your list is this one:

```
lst = ['a', 'test', 'b', 'c', 'test', 'd', 'e', 'test', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

then `uniformity_index = 1`. This index represents the *average number of indices* you need to move your 'test' words within your list in order to get a perfect uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the average distance between the words. You store the amount of steps between each findings and the next so you can measure dispersion.

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.